# Use search engine meta tag outside of the <head> section

Tags: seo, search-engine, meta-tags

I'm using a [meta tag](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=93710) to restrict access to specific parts of a website. The problem is that I'm using a CMS and I can only insert the `<meta>` tag inside the `<body>`, because the `<head>` sections is part of the universally used main template. Dose the `<meta>` tag still work outside the `<head>` section?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447842/what-happens-if-the-meta-tags-are-present-in-the-document-body

Comment: Fiddlesticks. Any idea how to insert a `meta` tag in an CMS without writing an module that moves the `meta` back to the `head` before sending the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish [the same effect as that meta tag using an HTTP header](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2007/07/robots-exclusion-protocol-now-with-even.html). The `X-Robots-Tag` can be set in an .htaccess file and will do the exact same thing as the meta tag. If your CMS doesn't support it you can always add it manually and it won't be affected by the CMS creates pages at all.

Comment: But how can you bind the HTTP Header to only be sent when a specific URL is called? Also, the thing is I want the user to enable the user to add the meta tag from the TinyMCE editor (in code view) without having to connect to the server via FTP, etc.

Comment: If you're doing it that way and the CMS can't add meta tags for you then you're out of options really. Either change CMSes to one that offers better customization, block whole directories, or give up on blocking search engines with this kind of customization.

Comment: Guess you are right, looks like a have to right a module that moves the meta tags back to the head. But thanks for your Help!