# redirect to a specific page from php

Tags: php

Hello I am using following code to open a page in PHP

```
header('Location :login.php');
```

but the problem is that this is doing inside the div of page, when I clicking on that the page is being loaded inside the DIV not on the fill screen, what should I write here to solve the problem?

edit

I am loading the page like this

javascript, in main.php

```
var div = document.getElementById('content');
var url = 'my.php';
div.innerHTML = '<iframe style="width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" src="' + url + '" />';
```

and I give a link to logout in my.php, here I need to open a login page and destroy the main.php page

Comment: are you loading via ajax?

Comment: no, the page is loaded into a div using javascript

Comment: so then you need to change the javascript to load it to `<body>` not to `<div>`

Comment: this is better to separate logic with template engine.

Comment: do you want to update information in-between div? if it's a logout button make the link to **login.php**, no need for javascript

Comment: The main.php page's DIV content has loaded the file my.php, if i open anything by using my.php it is loading into the content div, but I want to turn off this behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning a redirect (which redirects only your frame) like you do now, you'll have to have the top frame redirected.

Since your code gets loaded in an `IFRAME`, you'll need to change the TOP frame position, instead or returning a header, return the following javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.top.location = "http://www.example.com/path/login.php";
</script>
```

The trick is to use `window.top` instead of `window`.

Answer (score 1):

You are displaying stuff before header is sent.

```
if ( !headers_sent() ) {
    header("Location: login.php");
} else {
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=login.php">';
}
```

Javascript redirect.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location = "http://www.domain.com/login.php";
</script>
```

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. If his problem was really that he sent headers too late, he'd get a 'Headers alreay sent' PHP error. In that case, the META trick would be useless and ob_start() ob_clean() would be better. Anyway, that's not at all the problem he's having. EDIT: The jscript suggestion is a bit better, but won'T change the parent frame URL.

Comment: @Alex-Info.net i was going on information provided before update. it was a php problem that's turned into JavaScript. meta trick works.

Comment: Not META won't work unless he's lucky enough to still be in <HEAD> : http://stackoverflow.com/a/1447933/2446119