# Redirect a page without using the header

Tags: php, ajax, redirect

In my curent project, the header is only loaded once. all the rest of the project add and remove Windows with AJAX method.

Everything works great exept for one detail, since I can't change the header (The page is always loaded). How can I transfer a client to the logon screen if his session had expired?

So far I'm using (in my session class):

```
public function LoginRedirect() {
//This function will redirect the user to the login page if the session is not valid. Will send GET Reason.
    $urlMessage = rawurlencode(utf8_encode($this->ErrMsg));
    echo '<script language="javascript"> window.location = "' . $this->RedirectURL . '?ErrMsg=' . $urlMessage . '";</script>';
}
```

But I dont like using Javascript to redirect a page to the login screen. Is there any other trick I could used?

Thank you

Comment: You could build an Apache session management module in C I guess and have that deal with the sessions and redirects ... not sure I'd recommend it though - it seems like overkill :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use headers, you could set a `<meta>` tag to do the redirecting:

```
$newURL = $this->RedirectURL.'?ErrMsg='.$urlMessage;
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='.$newURL.'">';
```

Comment: Can I use the meta outside the head of the document? Since my document is already loaded, and the verification is done with AJAX)

Comment: It would ***technically*** be invalid markup, but browsers have developed ways to interpret broken markup so you ***can*** use it but it would be recommended to use them in the head element.  You can read more about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447842/what-happens-if-the-meta-tags-are-present-in-the-document-body  JavaScript redirect may be your best option.

Comment: Thank you, that what I thought, I'll try to figure a other way of doing so if I can. I would like to stay "xhtml strict" all the way! But you did answer my question.