# CountDown Timer Before Redirect In Pure PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, redirect

I am using a pure JavaScript count down timer that I shared below to redirect to a URL after some time and show the left time to visitor also.

DEMO: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7tg9nvjv/)

```
<form name="redirect" id="redirect"> 
You Will Be Redirected To Next Page After  <input size="1" name="redirect2" id="counter"></input>Seconds.
</form> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var countdownfrom=5
var currentsecond=document.redirect.redirect2.value=countdownfrom+1 
function countredirect(){ 
if (currentsecond!=0){ 
currentsecond-=1 
document.redirect.redirect2.value=currentsecond 
} 
else{ 
showIt() 
return 
} 
setTimeout("countredirect()",1000) 
} 
countredirect() 
function showIt() {
window.location.href = "http://jsfiddle.net/";
} 
</script>
```

Now I want the same function and features and work in pure PHP as you know that many old mobile browsers still does't not support JavaScript and many are using JavaScript blocker. So Is this possible to do the same in Pure `PHP`, no `<script>` tags.

### UPDATE:

I know the below codes but I want a count down timer too to show to the visitor.

- `<?php header('Refresh: 5; URL=http://jsfiddle.net/'); ?>`
- `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=http://jsfiddle.net/">`

Comment: @HassanHey this can't be done only with php you will need to use jquery or javascript with it. PHP is a server side scripting language you have to use client side language for this task

Comment: @Utkarsh Thanks. This is the perfect answer. Please add in the answer below..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer:

This can't be done only with php you will need to use jquery or javascript with it. PHP is a server side scripting language you have to use client side language for this task.

### Tip:

For redirecting purpose Just use `header()` function in php to redirect the php file in some time.Your code should look like this

```
<?php
    header( "refresh:5;url=http://jsfiddle.net" );
?>
```

Hope this helps you...

Comment: Bro i have edited my answer please choose this answer as correct

Answer (score 1):

Well if you want some output, you can't use `header()`. Alternatively, you could do something like this:

```
echo "<pre>";
echo "Loading ...";

ob_flush();
flush();

$x = 0;
while($x <= 4) {
    $x++;
    echo '<br/>'. $x;
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    sleep(1);
}

echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://jsfiddle.net/">';
```

Comment: Your code make me to vote up. Rest I want to show only remaining sec not all like `5,4,3,2,1`. Is this possible to show only one characters for left time as http://jsfiddle.net/7tg9nvjv/ ?

Comment: @MuhammadHassan well if you want a descending countdown just initialize the counter to 5 then decrement it inside the loop, regarding the one by one, you can't do that, thats the limitation

Comment: It mean that I selected the right Answer. Thanks for confirming more.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server-side language. You cannot control how the browser behaves from PHP without some quite complex setup. And even that, you cannot guarantee the behaviour of showing a countdown without JavaScript. For browsers who restrict JavaScript execution, the `Refresh` header will work just fine. However, for those having JavaScript enabled (which is the majority of browsers nowadays, desktop and mobile alike), a simple header will not give any UI feedback and is frustrating for users who expect responsive applications and web pages.

For this reason, JavaScript can be added, if available, to enhance the automatic, delayed, redirection and give the user some feedback of what's going on. Those with JavaScript disabled will just see a static page, telling them that the page will be redirected, and how long they have to wait for it.

### PHP

```
<?php

  $redirectTimeout = 5;   // seconds

  header('Refresh:' . $redirectTimeout . ';url=http://jsfiddle.net');

  // ...

  // inside your <head>, add this
  echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" ' . 
             'content="' . $redirectTimeout . ';url=http://jsfiddle.net">';

  // ...

  // inside your <body>, add this (or something similar)
  echo '<div>' . 
         'You will be redirected to next page after ' .
         '<span id="redirectCountdownLabel">' . 
           $redirectTimeout . 
         '</span> seconds' .
       '</div>';

  // ...

  // add JS below
```

### JavaScript

For this part, I recommend you use jQuery. It will not only write safer and cross-browser JS, it will also make your code smaller and prettier. This part can be put anywhere in your HTML, or inside a `.js` file that you add with a `<script>` tag. For convenience, you can even add jQuery using a [CDN](http://code.jquery.com/).

```
!function() {

$(function () {
  var meta = $('head meta[http-equiv="refresh"]');
  var label = $('#redirectCountdownLabel');
  var loadTime;
  var refreshTimeout;

  if (meta.length && label.length) {
    loadTime = window.performance.timing.domComplete;
    refreshTimeout = parseInt(meta.attr('content'), 10); // seconds

    new Timer(refreshTimeout * 1000, loadTime).start(200, function (elapsed) {
      // "elapsed" ms / 1000 = sec
      label.text(refreshTimeout - parseInt(elapsed / 1000));
    });
  }
});

function Timer(maxTime, startTime) {
  var timeout;
  var callback;

  startTime = startTime || Date.now();

  function nextTimer(delay) {
    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
      var curTime = Date.now();
      var elapsedTime = curTime - startTime;

      callback(elapsedTime);

      if (elapsedTime < maxTime) {
        nextTimer(delay);
      }
    }, delay);
  }

  this.start = function start(ms, cb) {
    stop();
    callback = cb;        
    nextTimer(ms);
  };

  this.stop = function stop() {
    if (timeout) {
      clearTimeout(timeout);   
    }
  };
};


}();
```

(**Note**: here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YanickRochon/re8hf0Ld/) of the `Timer` class.)

Comment: You answer is overfilling my question. I don't want to use JavaScript and you added JQuery too. Simple I want a countdown redirect for JavaScript blocked browsers that is not it.

Comment: Right, however this answer takes what you got and makes it work with both JavaScript-enabled and JavaScript-disabled browsers. Since your delay is actually 5 seconds, and the other answers do not display a proper counter, it may frustrate the user who'd think his/her device takes a long time to respond; in short, it's a matter of UI feedback. Those who do not enable JS will not see anything, however most browsers *do* enable JS nowadays, therefore you cover a majority of use case, while preserving the same behaviour in the end. Just saying. I'll edit the answer to reflect this comment.

Comment: You can check http://stackoverflow.com/a/25360351/3170029 that is working fine with all my requirement but is showing all sec like `5,4,3,2,1 -> redirect` that I don't want. I just want to make sure the visitor that page is working instead of giving the hidden redirect in </head> only.

Comment: The answer you point to seems to output stuff in the `<head>` element, then append a `<meta>`; this won't work as the browser will not render anything in the `<head>`. And if the `<meta>` is appended to the `<body>`, then it becomes [invalid HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447842/what-happens-if-the-meta-tags-are-present-in-the-document-body). Also, the answer you chose as "acceptable" will not render anything and will just make the page "hang" for 5 seconds before redirecting, JavaScript enabled, or not. My answer cover all cases.

Comment: The answer I choose is based upon `This can't be done only with php`. Rest that I mentioned in above comment is tested by me and working. I added all that code in `<body></body>.

Comment: Note, this answer has been saying that `This can't be done only with PHP`, not just in this phrasing. Anyhow.

Comment: The answer is temporarily until anyone else didn't give the solution. The reason that why I don't want to use SCRIPT is my visitors are using OPERA MINI and that is very harsh to SCRIPTS.

Comment: *That* was not part of the question. And, in my opinion, at this time, non-standard browsers should be discouraged, and not adapted for. Even MS wants to ban IE7!

Comment: Yes that's why I asked no SCRIPTS, pure PHP only. I am still stick to my question so don't proceed with JQuery or JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

```
scusate per prima, ho postato male, sono ali inizi, sorry
<?php
echo "<pre>";
echo "Loading ...";
ob_flush();
flush();
$x = 21;
while($x >= 1) {
$x--;
echo '<br/>'. $x;
ob_flush();
flush();
sleep(1);
}
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://jsfiddle.net/">';
```

Comment: This Site is English only. Please translate and correct your formatting by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50765202/edit) your post

Answer (score -2):

To do the countdown, so it seems to work or am I wrong?

```
<?php
echo "Loading ...";
ob_flush();
flush();
$x = 21;
while($x >= 1) {
    $x--;
    echo '<br/>'. $x;
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    sleep(1);
}
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh"content="0;url=http://jsfiddle.net/">';
?>`
```