# HTML metadata in body

Tags: html

I am creating some HTML fragements, the fragements will be wrapped in a DIV tag - ie its parent.

I do not have access to the DIV parent tag.

The fragment could be anything.

I want to be able to distinguish between different fragments. My idea was to insert a html element as metadata as the first element in the fragement.

The parent div can then identify what type it is by searching its first child for the meta information.

ie

```
<div class="parent">
  <metatag fragement="fragementid"/>
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
</div>
```

My question is, is there a HTML tag for this purpose?

Comment: You can add a hidden p tag and add the additional info to that tag

Comment: I could use any tag, but is there a "meta" one?

Comment: Noop there are not meta tags for this.
Refer: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447842/what-happens-if-the-meta-tags-are-present-in-the-document-body

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go through: http://www.w3.org/tr/html401/struct/global.html for better understanding on HTML structure.

Still you can add meta information to your tags by using an additional hidden tag.
Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/w49g19bw/

```
<p data-meta="HN SPECS" class="hidden"></p> 

.hidden {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Why use a hidden `p` element here, instead of placing that data attribute on the parent element itself?

Comment: @Cbroe as stated in the question: "I do not have access to the DIV parent tag."

Comment: Ah, overlooked that. Would still rather go for something “neutral” like an empty `span` element, rather than a paragraph. Or put the identifier on the first child element that’s gonna be there in any case, instead of introducing an additional one just for this purpose.

Comment: CBroe I will follow that advise!