# using the <meta> tag with microformats properties

Tags: meta-tags, meta, microformats

I need to add author and updated properties to my hentry schema to comply with [microformats.org](https://microformats.org), however, I don't want to display this data on the actual web page.  With [schema.org](https://schema.org) markup I use the meta tag to provide the required properties if I don't want them to be visible.  Can I do this for microformats.org too?  If so how would I write it?  Like this?

```
<meta class="author vcard" content="AUTHOUR NAME">
```

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you are asking if `<meta>` tag can be used outside of `<head>` See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447842/what-happens-if-the-meta-tags-are-present-in-the-document-body

Comment: Well no not exactly but that is good to know.  I'm asking how to add the REQUIRED microformats properties to a page if I don't want to actually display those properties to the user.  For example, I'm required to add the author property to my hentry but I don't want to show the user who the author is.

Comment: You can set the content to `display : none` and it won't show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microformats are HTML in their most basic form, and they perform exactly like HTML does in the wild. If you don't want the content to show while utilizing Microformats you're going to have to use a technique to not show the content on the page.
NOTE:  take caution when doing this, and properly research the technique you use to ensure that you are not breaking document flow utilized by screen readers, other forms of assistive technology, as well as power users and their techniques.
As mentioned in the comment to the question, you can use `display:none`, `visibility:hidden`, and even in some cases `text-indent:-9999px`, but which is proper for your instance is something you'll have to decide as you work through it.