# Can I add a Twitter Card without putting it in the <head> tag?

Tags: html, twitter, metadata, twitter-card

I am trying to find a way around putting the Twitter Card Meta Data within the `<head>` tag of my site. Unable to access this at present so is it possible to add it somewhere else within the code?

Answer (score 0):

This is invalid HTML and not recommended. Why don't you have access to the `<head>`?

Read this: [What happens if the meta tags are present in the document body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447842/what-happens-if-the-meta-tags-are-present-in-the-document-body)

I suggest searching before asking a question that has been answered before.

Comment: While this is deemed as invalid markup, <meta> tags within the body are still viable through search engines, as per Schema markup. I did search for this topic immensely, but given this topic you have shared is not what I am after, I thought it would be a good idea to ask for help. I am unable to access the <head> due to the restrictions on the CMS I work with.

Comment: I would never suggest poor markup when I know better but if you can't do it any other way, then try it and see what happens.