# Can I add meta description anywhere on the page?

Tags: html, meta-tags

I know it's not supposed to be done this way, but I am using sites.google and I am very limited in what I can edit and where I can insert code.

Is it possible to put a `meta` `description` (such as the one below) in the middle of the page's code (start of the page content) and have it work?

```
<meta name="description" content="Premier East Valley Realty
specializing in luxury real estate. We are your location
specialists.">
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "have it work"?

Answer (score 0):

This question kind of duplicates with [this entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447842/what-happens-if-the-meta-tags-are-present-in-the-document-body).

The **answer** there:

> This is of course invalid as per HTML4.01. META tags are only allowed
>   within HEAD (just like, say, TITLE) so by putting it into a BODY,
>   you're essentially creating an invalid markup.