# How to add meta tags dynamically in Blazor SPA

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

I'm converting my Razor MVC website to Blazor SPA. In my existing site, I was passing meta tag value dynamically according to page e.g

```
<head>
<meta property="og:title" content="@ViewBag.Title" />
</head>
```

Is there any way to achieve same in Blazor? Adding meta tags inside body is [invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1447933/4140278)

Answer (score 1):

Someone has already done great work and it works well.

Check this [link](https://github.com/jsakamoto/Toolbelt.Blazor.HeadElement) for complete code and example.

```
@* This is "Pages/Counter.razor" *@
@page "/counter"

<Meta Property="ogp:title" Content="Counter" />
```

Comment: For those who wish to add a tag to ```_Host.cshtml``` that requires ```NavigationManager```, such as the ```og:url``` tag, put it in the ```MainLayout.razor``` file instead

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in your razor component

```
@page "/"
<HeadContent>
<link href='/Images/logo.svg' rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Your Title" />
</HeadContent>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new class like this one

```
public class AppBase : ComponentBase
{
    protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.OpenComponent<Head>(0);
        builder.CloseComponent();
    }
}
```

then create a razor page called "Head" where you put all the dynamic stuff.

On the _Host.cshtml, inside the head tags put the following code

```
<head>
    <component type="typeof(AppBase)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
<head>
```

and add the scope in Startup.cs

```
services.AddScoped<AppBase>();
```